# Export/Build Node.js Server

Tags: javascript, node.js

My first problem is, that I don't know what my problem is called.

I'm coding a game in JavaScript. The client runs with Node.js and Electron. It's possible to build this as a user friendly desktop app. [User can start app without installing packages or using the console]

Now there's one thing, I don't know how to deal with. For multiplayer gaming I need a sever. I'm using a second Node.js Server, which the clients connect with. That's no problem, but: The server should be user-friendly too. At the moment you have to install node and start the server in the console.

How it's possible to build the server, so that it's easily started by doubleclicking on an icon. Like a desktopapp, made with Electron.

Maybe you know something, can give me some words to Google or something else.

Comment: You can use the same server and use multiple sockets

Comment: You could use an executable packaging software, including the Node.js executable, to store ALL the project in it (note that you may need to check the Node.js license, you may not be allowed to do that).

Or simply use a script depending on the target platform (BAT, shell script, etc.).

Comment: I think an "executable packaging software" is someting like Electron? Script sounds nice too, already thought about this. But than every user has to install node manually...